# Replace String in property file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a properties file where certain string shoudl  be replaced with Jenkins parameter. I ahve tried using the variable directly in the Properties file which did not work.

**properties file**

```
DOCKER_TAG_SUFFIX=-REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION
PROPERTY_FILE_PATH=someproperty
```

**Jenkinsfile snippet**

```
def jboss_parameters = readProperties file: jboss_propfile
jboss_parameters .replaceAll("RELEASE_VERSION",params.RELEASE_VERSION) # try1
jboss_parameters = readFile(jboss_propfile).replaceAll("REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION",params.RELEASE_VERSION) # try2
# try 3
jboss_parameters.each{k,v -> 
     if (v == "REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION" ) 
        jboss_parameters.setProperty($k,params.RELEASE_VERSION)
     } 
# try 4
def jboss_source_file = new File(jboss_propfile)
def jboss_parameters = jboss_source_file.text.replace("REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION",params.RELEASE_VERSION)
```

I am not able to find another way that works for me.

`println jboss_parameters` output

> {DOCKER_TAG_SUFFIX=-REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION, PROPERTY_FILE_PATH=someproperty}

Answer (score 1):

The [readProperties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) step returns a dictionary (map), not a string, that is crated from the properties file.
Your first attempt (`# try1`) fails because maps in groovy do not have a `replaceAll` function like strings have and therefore you will get an error.
Your  third attempt (`# try3`) is failing because you are comparing the map values to `REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION` without the `-` character and therefore the comparison always fails and no values are changed.
I tested the second attempt (`# try 2`) and it seems to be working, so i am not sure what is your issue, but it is easier to handle properties as a map instead of a string that is retuned from the `readFile` method.

So if you have only specific properties that need to be updated you can update them directly:

```groovy
 def jboss_parameters = readProperties file: jboss_propfile
 jboss_parameters.DOCKER_TAG_SUFFIX = params.RELEASE_VERSION // update relevant property
```

Or if you have multiple properties that should be modified you can iterate and update each value using the `collectEntries` method. Something like:

```groovy
 def jboss_parameters = readProperties file: jboss_propfile
 updated_parameters = jboss_parameters.collectEntries { key, value ->
     [key, value.replaceAll("REPLACE_RELEASE_VERSION",params.RELEASE_VERSION)]
 }
```